# How do you add separate test files with Catch2 and CMake?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, catch2

In the [documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md#top), they only compile a single file `test.cpp` which presumably contains all the tests. I want to separate my individual tests from the file that contains `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN`, like [so](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/slow-compiles.md#top).

If I have a file `test.cpp` which contains `#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN` and a separate test file `simple_test.cpp`, I've managed to produce an executable that contains the test in `simple_test.cpp` this way:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(tests test.cpp simple_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(tests)
```

However, is this an acceptable way of producing the executable? From different tutorials, if I had more tests, I should be able to make a library of test sources and link them to `test.cpp` to produce the executable:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

add_library(test_sources simple_test.cpp another_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_sources Catch2::Catch2)

add_executable(tests test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests test_sources)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(tests)
```

But when I tried this, I got a CMake Warning `Test executable ... contains no tests!`.

To summarize, should I be making a library of tests? If so, how can I make it contain my tests. Otherwise, is it correct to be adding my new test.cpp files to the `add_executable` function?

Comment: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/720 https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/421 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227598/how-can-i-use-catch2-to-test-my-cmake-static-library-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do you add separate test files with Catch2 and CMake?

Use object libraries or use `--Wl,--whole-archive`. Linker removes unreferenced symbols from static libraries when linking, so the tests are not in the final executable.

> Could you give an example CMakeLists.txt?

Like

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

add_library(test_sources OBJECT simple_test.cpp another_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_sources Catch2::Catch2)

add_executable(tests test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests test_sources)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(tests)
```

or

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

add_library(test_sources simple_test.cpp another_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_sources Catch2::Catch2)

add_executable(tests test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests -Wl,--whole-archive test_sources -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(tests)
```

Comment: Could you give an example CMakeLists.txt? I don't know what object libraries are.

Comment: It's given in of the links I linked in your question... CMake has also great online documentation - you may read about object libraries in a lot of places.