# Catch2 CLion error, "No tests were found"

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, catch2

I have a folder structure like

[image]

and I am trying to get Catch2 setup, my CMake files look like:

the topmost CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(throwaway)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)

add_executable(foo_main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_main PUBLIC foo_lib)
```

my `src` CMake:

```
add_subdirectory(foo)
```

my `src/foo` CMake:

```
add_library(foo_lib Foo.cpp)
```

my `tests` CMake:

```
add_subdirectory(foo)

add_executable(foo_test catch_runner.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_test PUBLIC
        foo_test_lib)
```

my `tests/foo` CMake

```
add_library(foo_test_lib
        FooTests.cpp)

target_link_libraries(foo_test_lib PUBLIC
        foo_lib)
```

From there, I used Clion's Catch2 integration to set up my run config as
[image]

so nothing crazy here

However, I get this error:
[image]

I discovered that the error goes away if I edit the `tests` CMake into

```
add_executable(foo_test catch_runner.cpp foo/FooTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo_test PUBLIC foo_lib)
```

and the test works as expected. But I obviously don't want to manually add each file into an executable, I want to be able to make a library that I can just slap the `catch_runner` into.

I have no clue why the test doesn't work when I link it as a library, but works when I add it manually. Any ideas?

Comment: this is on catch2 2.13.9, the last one with a single header include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out it from the links at [How do you add separate test files with Catch2 and CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499778/how-do-you-add-separate-test-files-with-catch2-and-cmake)

in my `tests/foo` CMake I changed it to

```
add_library(foo_test_lib OBJECT
        FooTests.cpp)

target_link_libraries(foo_test_lib PUBLIC
        foo_lib)
```